# foreach not exporting to csv

Tags: azure, powershell

So i want to know how many devices a user has enrolled in azure.  the script give me what i want but im having 2 problems:

1. i want to display every command on a different column( the user name -  number of devices)
2. im not able to import all to a csv file.

---

```
 $usuarios = Get-Content .\usersid.csv

 ForEach ($usuario in $usuarios){

 Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $usuario | select userprincipalname
 
 (Get-AzureADUserRegisteredDevice -ObjectId $usuario).count | Export-Csv  -append.\cuenta.csv

 }
```

Comment: You specified `.count | Export-Csv -append .\cuenta.csv` so the only thing being passed to `Export-Csv` is the count of devices, not an array of objects that `Export-Csv` is expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Like @theMadTechnician mentioned, the only thing being passed to `Export-CSV` is the count of the devices.

You could create a Custom PS Object, build values (array of username and Devices) in the custom object and export them as a CSV.

```
$usuarios = Get-Content .\usersid.csv
$items = @()

 ForEach ($usuario in $usuarios)
 
 {
  $username = (Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $usuario).userprincipalname
  $count = (Get-AzureADUserRegisteredDevice -ObjectId $usuario).count
  $item = New-Object PSCustomObject
  $item | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "UserName"  -NotePropertyValue $username
  $item | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Count"  -NotePropertyValue $count
  $items += $item

 }

 $items |  Export-Csv -Path D:\DevicesCount.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation
```